# Alternative of ContentPresenter with selected item in wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, selecteditem, selectedindexchanged

Are any controls or kind of, with `selectedindexchanged` event or property `selecteditem` maybe?

I use `ContentPresenter` now and me need some solution for getting index of selected item issue. With `DataTemplate` inside, it's desirable.

My code looks:

```
<Border BorderThickness="1">
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Path=Value}">
    <ContentPresenter.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type System:String}">
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContentPresenter}}}" 
                 TextAlignment="Left"
                 BorderThickness="0"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type System:Int32}">
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContentPresenter}}}" 
                 TextAlignment="Left"
                 BorderThickness="0"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type System:Double}">
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContentPresenter}}}" 
                 TextAlignment="Left"
                 BorderThickness="0"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type System:Boolean}">
            <Border Background="White">
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContentPresenter}}}" 
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentPresenter.Resources>
</ContentPresenter>
</Border>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need an `ItemsControl` or its derivates `ListView`, `ListBox`, `DataGrid` etc. They have `SelectedItem` property on them.

In order to set the `ItemTemplate` depending on the any criteria, use `DataTemplateSelector` and set `Itemscontrol.Itemtemplateselector` property. Details at msdn

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplateselector(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplateselector%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)